# Does the GLSL sign() function cause branching and how does it work?

Tags: glsl

It seems like some functions that have outputs in cases might use an if statement as the underlying implementation, thus causing branching. I don't think it does, but I wonder.

For sign(x), if the number is positive, negative, or zero, it reruns 1, -1 and 0 respectively.

So how does this function work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Implementation details are always implementation-specific. So how this construct is implemented depends entirely on the vendor (and ultimatively, the abilities of the underlying hardware).

However, it is extremely unlikely that any real-world implementation would use a branch for the `sign()` opertation. The sign can be easily determined by looking at the sign bit which is present in most real-world floating-point formats, especially [IEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). This can be easily implemented with logic - much easier as your typical floating point arithmetic function.

Comment: I don't think sign is implemented using branches... but the logic is not as simple as getting the sign bit, because the sign function returns 0.0 when the value is 0.0 (so it needs to test for zero); if the value is not zero, only then the sign bit can be used. This means that all bits of the IEEE floating point must be used to determine the result.